# Sending Data From Activity to Fragment returns error

Tags: android, android-fragments

I use Bundle approach from this link:https://stackoverflow.com/a/21102881/2641960

but i faced with this error:

```
 -15 11:14:47.323    8558-8558/co.kssg.expertnote E/InputEventReceiver﹕      Exception dispatching input event.
 04-15 11:14:47.323    8558-8558/co.kssg.expertnote E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕      Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
 04-15 11:14:47.333    8558-8558/co.kssg.expertnote E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕      java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
```

Here is my Method to Send Bundle Data To Fragment:

```
public void sendDataToFragment (String data)
{
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    MainActivity ac = new MainActivity();
    FragmentManager fManager = ac.getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fManager.beginTransaction();
    bundle.putString("message", data );
    DataFragment dataFragment = new DataFragment();
    dataFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    transaction.replace(R.id.sFLayout, dataFragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

this method is placed in a custom ImageView Class.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this `MainActivity ac = new MainActivity();` is not working.

You should add a reference in the constructor of your ImageView Class like this :

```
public class ImageView {
    private Activity mainActivity;

    public void ImageView(Activity mainActivity) {
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }

    public void sendDataToFragment (String data){
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        FragmentManager fManager = mainActivity.getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fManager.beginTransaction();
        bundle.putString("message", data );
        DataFragment dataFragment = new DataFragment();
        dataFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        transaction.replace(R.id.sFLayout, dataFragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Max thanks for your help, i need to try it

Comment: Thanks @Maxouille , My Problem Solved by Sending MainActivity with Static Method of ImageView class